# How do I parse a cmd line variable into 2-parts?

Tags: bash

This is my first post here. Absolute newbie here - plz be gentle :)

(%2=mydomain.ddns.net and mydomain.com into $SUB_DOMAIN . DOMAIN

```
./test.sh <name> <dydomain.com> 
./test.sh <name> <mysub.domain.com>
```

would both produce the same result.

```
var1=<name>
var2=<subdomain> # if present
var3=<domain>

url=<$var1.$var2.$var3>
```

Regardless of the existance of a subdomain or not, I need $url to be complete with

```
<name>.(subdomain).<domain>
```

UPDATE: Thanks everyone for prompt responses, I am currently reading through the answers provided and testing. This script will be run remotely on a VPS HOST so I would need the script to fail and exit if there are unbound variables. I could not prompt for user input.

Thank you.

Comment: please edit your Q to show before versus after of your input. As this site is about helping your fix your programming, you should also include your best attempt to solve the problem. Do you know about `sed` ? Do you know about bash parameter substitutions? Either of those offer common solutions. Also, your subject title should not contain the main information related to your question. That should be in the body of your question. Move the parenthetic information into the body of yoru Q. Good luck.

Comment: The ideal question will have a small set of data, maybe just one line, that can be copy/pasted into a readers local terminal to experience the same problem you are. ... Also, use https://shellcheck.net to "vet" any code you are going to post. You want to have code that doesn't generate any errors due to syntax issues (as you have now). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks *shellter*, the (http://shellcheck.net) is very handy. I have seen implementations of `sed` but I am so new at first its hard to decode. I do knot know about bash substitutions. (but I will look it up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boo="mydomain.ddns.net"
```

- using '-d .' with 'cut' , given string divided in multiple fields with '.' as delimiter.
- '-f1' with cut displays only field 1 and '-f2,3' displays 2 and 3 fields.

```
echo $boo | cut -f1 -d.
mydomain

echo $boo | cut -f2,3 -d.
ddns.net

var1=$(echo $boo | cut -f1 -d.)
var2=$(echo $boo | cut -f2,3 -d.)

echo $var1
mydomain

echo $var2
ddns.net
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.